# Create a new DataFrame with first 8 NON-NULL values of existing DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe of n weeks and I wish to extract the first 4 weeks with non-zero values and create a new dataframe off that.

```py
df_1 = pd.DataFrame([{
  'CohortSize': 489, 202141: 1,
  202142: 0.26,
  202143: 0.11,
  202144: 0.08,
  202145: 0.06,
  202146: 0.04,
  202147: 0.03,
  202148: 0.02,
  202149: 0.02,
  202150: 0.01,
  202151: 0.01,
  202152: 0.01,
  202201: 0.01,
  202202: 0.01,
  202203: 0.01,
  202204: 0.01,
  202205: 0.01,
  202206: 0.01,
  202207: 0.01,
  202208: 0.01,
  202209: 0.01,
  202210: 0.01,
  202211: 0.01,
  202212: 0.01,
  202213: 0.01,
  202214: 0.0},
 {'CohortSize': 484, 202141: np.nan,
  202142: 1,
  202143: 0.25,
  202144: 0.12,
  202145: 0.07,
  202146: 0.04,
  202147: 0.03,
  202148: 0.02,
  202149: 0.02,
  202150: 0.02,
  202151: 0.01,
  202152: 0.01,
  202201: 0.01,
  202202: 0.01,
  202203: 0.01,
  202204: 0.01,
  202205: 0.01,
  202206: 0.01,
  202207: 0.01,
  202208: 0.01,
  202209: 0.01,
  202210: 0.01,
  202211: 0.01,
  202212: 0.01,
  202213: 0.01,
  202214: 0.0},
 {'CohortSize': 410, 202141: np.nan,
  202142: np.nan,
  202143: 1,
  202144: 0.29,
  202145: 0.12,
  202146: 0.08,
  202147: 0.06,
  202148: 0.05,
  202149: 0.03,
  202150: 0.02,
  202151: 0.02,
  202152: 0.01,
  202201: 0.01,
  202202: 0.01,
  202203: 0.01,
  202204: 0.01,
  202205: 0.01,
  202206: 0.01,
  202207: 0.01,
  202208: 0.01,
  202209: 0.01,
  202210: 0.01,
  202211: 0.01,
  202212: 0.01,
  202213: 0.01,
  202214: 0.0},
 {'CohortSize': 327, 202141: np.nan,
  202142: np.nan,
  202143: np.nan,
  202144: 1,
  202145: 0.33,
  202146: 0.15,
  202147: 0.11,
  202148: 0.07,
  202149: 0.06,
  202150: 0.04,
  202151: 0.03,
  202152: 0.02,
  202201: 0.02,
  202202: 0.02,
  202203: 0.02,
  202204: 0.02,
  202205: 0.01,
  202206: 0.01,
  202207: 0.01,
  202208: 0.01,
  202209: 0.01,
  202210: 0.01,
  202211: 0.01,
  202212: 0.01,
  202213: 0.01,
  202214: 0.01},
 {'CohortSize': 309, 202141: np.nan,
  202142: np.nan,
  202143: np.nan,
  202144: np.nan,
  202145: 1,
  202146: 0.32,
  202147: 0.17,
  202148: 0.11,
  202149: 0.08,
  202150: 0.06,
  202151: 0.04,
  202152: 0.03,
  202201: 0.03,
  202202: 0.02,
  202203: 0.02,
  202204: 0.02,
  202205: 0.01,
  202206: 0.01,
  202207: 0.01,
  202208: 0.01,
  202209: 0.01,
  202210: 0.01,
  202211: 0.01,
  202212: 0.01,
  202213: 0.01,
  202214: 0.01},
 {'CohortSize': 259, 202141: np.nan,
  202142: np.nan,
  202143: np.nan,
  202144: np.nan,
  202145: np.nan,
  202146: 1,
  202147: 0.35,
  202148: 0.18,
  202149: 0.11,
  202150: 0.08,
  202151: 0.05,
  202152: 0.03,
  202201: 0.03,
  202202: 0.03,
  202203: 0.02,
  202204: 0.02,
  202205: 0.01,
  202206: 0.01,
  202207: 0.01,
  202208: 0.01,
  202209: 0.01,
  202210: 0.01,
  202211: 0.01,
  202212: 0.01,
  202213: 0.01,
  202214: 0.01},
 {'CohortSize': 269, 202141: np.nan,
  202142: np.nan,
  202143: np.nan,
  202144: np.nan,
  202145: np.nan,
  202146: np.nan,
  202147: 1,
  202148: 0.29,
  202149: 0.14,
  202150: 0.1,
  202151: 0.06,
  202152: 0.04,
  202201: 0.03,
  202202: 0.03,
  202203: 0.02,
  202204: 0.02,
  202205: 0.02,
  202206: 0.02,
  202207: 0.02,
  202208: 0.02,
  202209: 0.02,
  202210: 0.02,
  202211: 0.02,
  202212: 0.02,
  202213: 0.02,
  202214: 0.01}])
```

| index | CohortSize | 202141 | 202142 | 202143 | 202144 | 202145 | 202146 | 202147 | 202148 | 202149 | 202150 | 202151 | 202152 | 202201 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 489 | 1.0 | 0.26 | 0.11 | 0.08 | 0.06 | 0.04 | 0.03 | 0.02 | 0.02 | 0.01 | 0.01 | 0.01 | NaN |
| 1 | 484 | NaN | 1.0 | 0.25 | 0.12 | 0.07 | 0.04 | 0.03 | 0.02 | 0.02 | 0.02 | 0.01 | 0.01 | 0.01 |
| 2 | 410 | NaN | NaN | 1.0 | 0.29 | 0.12 | 0.08 | 0.06 | 0.05 | 0.03 | 0.02 | 0.02 | 0.01 | 0.01 |
| 3 | 327 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 1.0 | 0.33 | 0.15 | 0.11 | 0.07 | 0.06 | 0.04 | 0.03 | 0.02 | 0.02 |
| 4 | 309 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 1.0 | 0.32 | 0.17 | 0.11 | 0.08 | 0.06 | 0.04 | 0.03 | 0.03 |
| 5 | 259 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 1.0 | 0.35 | 0.18 | 0.11 | 0.08 | 0.05 | 0.03 | 0.03 |
| 6 | 269 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 1.0 | 0.29 | 0.14 | 0.1 | 0.06 | 0.04 | 0.03 |

after transforming i wish for the dataframe to look like this

```py
df_2 = pd.DataFrame([{
  'CohortSize': 489,
  'week 1': 0.26,
  'week 2': 0.11,
  'week 3': 0.08,
  'week 4': 0.06},
 {'CohortSize': 484,
  'week 1': 0.25,
  'week 2': 0.12,
  'week 3': 0.07,
  'week 4': 0.04},
 {'CohortSize': 410,
  'week 1': 0.29,
  'week 2': 0.12,
  'week 3': 0.08,
  'week 4': 0.06},
 {'CohortSize': 327,
  'week 1': 0.33,
  'week 2': 0.15,
  'week 3': 0.11,
  'week 4': 0.07},
 {'CohortSize': 309,
  'week 1': 0.32,
  'week 2': 0.17,
  'week 3': 0.11,
  'week 4': 0.08},
 {'CohortSize': 259,
  'week 1': 0.35,
  'week 2': 0.18,
  'week 3': 0.11,
  'week 4': 0.08},
 {'CohortSize': 269,
  'week 1': 0.29,
  'week 2': 0.14,
  'week 3': 0.1,
  'week 4': 0.06}])
```

| index | CohortSize | week 1 | week 2 | week 3 | week 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 489 | 0.26 | 0.11 | 0.08 | 0.06 |
| 1 | 484 | 0.25 | 0.12 | 0.07 | 0.04 |
| 2 | 410 | 0.29 | 0.12 | 0.08 | 0.06 |
| 3 | 327 | 0.33 | 0.15 | 0.11 | 0.07 |
| 4 | 309 | 0.32 | 0.17 | 0.11 | 0.08 |
| 5 | 259 | 0.35 | 0.18 | 0.11 | 0.08 |
| 6 | 269 | 0.29 | 0.14 | 0.1 | 0.06 |

Answer (score 0):

This works for all but your last row, which I think might have been a typo. Also, your expected answer had 4 weeks but you stated that you wanted 8. I followed the expected dataframe:

```
column_names = []
number_of_weeks = 4
for j in range(number_of_weeks):
    column_names.append("Week" + str(j+1))
    
res = []
for i in range(len(df_1)):
    vals = df_1.iloc[i].dropna()[2:2+number_of_weeks]
    res.append(vals.values)
df = pd.DataFrame(res)
df.columns = column_names
df.insert(0, "CohortSize", df_1.CohortSize)
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, but if i needed this to work for n number of weeks eg 50 weeks, how do i achieve with out individually renaming the columns and specifying the range to drop na since the number of na's increase by each row.

Comment: I have changed the answer after looking at your comments. You can now choose the number of weeks you want to include.